# How to keep the selected date in the DatePicker in DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datepicker

I have a problem with the DatePicker in a DataGrid. When I click the first time in a cell DatePicker displays the current date me, but when I click next cell DataGridTextColumn date changes to the default 01-01-0001. How to keep the selected date in the DatePicker in DataGrid?

```
                           <!--------------------------------------xaml------------------------------------------->
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Data" Width="70">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataZdarzenia, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy', Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                           <!--------------------------------------xaml------------------------------------------->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way

Create a DataConverter Class

```
 public class DateConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        if (date != null && date.Year != 1)
        {
            return date;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return DateTime.MinValue;

        DateTime val;
        if (value.ToString() == " ")
            return DateTime.MinValue;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val))
            return val;
        else
            return DateTime.MinValue;
    }
}
```

in the XAML add this code for resource

```
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Progject.Control.Converter.WPF"

    <UserControl.Resources>
    <l:DateConverter x:Key="dateConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and in the section grid when you have a datepiker insert this code:

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="StartDate" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding StartDate}"  Header="Start date" IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=StartDate,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        </DatePicker>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StartDate,Mode=TwoWay,StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy},Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Binding should be TwoWay

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataZdarzenia, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='dd-MM-yyyy', Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your DataZdarzenia property? Or your converter?

Comment: Yes, I did not see anything suspicious. When I delete converter, effect was the same.

Comment: Put a get and a set on the property and see if the Binding sets a value on it, then you can see who turns it back.

Comment: Very incomplete answer